# Case insensitive ORDERBY in wpquery

Tags: wp-query, mysql, sort

I'm trying to sort custom posts in alphabetical order, and I've just now realized that capital letters are being sorted before lowercase. Two restaurants start with 'Cal' and 'CAT' with 'CAT' being returned as the first in alphabetical order.

Here're my $args:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'chef',
    'meta_key' => 'restaurant',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

I've also tried changing the 'orderby' to 'LOWER(restaurant)' but had no success with that.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/319672/edit) to provide more context (is your `$args` argument used in a `WP_Query`, or `pre_get_posts`, or (shudder) [`query_posts()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/16121), for example).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have set your orderby incorrectly... you don't set the metakey and orderby to the same.

try changing

```
'orderby' => 'restaurant',
```

to

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
```

this link may help https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Per the docs you posted, it should be `orderby => 'meta_value'` to sort by the `restaurant` metadata.

Comment: ack  You're correct.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it doesn't change my sort at all. 'CAT' still shows up before 'Cal'

Answer (score 0):

1. As stated above, your `orderby` parameter should be set to `meta_value`, not `restaurant`.
2. Using phpMyAdmin or some other tool, look at your database. With any newer installation of WordPress, your tables should have a collation of `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. That means that the table is storing its data in UTF-8 4-byte unicode character set. That "ci" at the end means "case insensitive".

If your collation is not correct, then you may need to convert your data. This is not as easy as it sounds all the time, so make sure you get a quality backup of your database first.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for that tidbit. I'll have a look. It's on Pantheon, so I'm not sure I can change it.

Comment: Yeah, all collations on wp_postmeta:meta_value are utf8mb4_unicode_ci so this is not the problem.